# Is it really necessary to show my name/link next to every flag when I'm reviewing a list of flags I've cast?

Tags: discussion, flag-history

Out of curiosity, what is the point of having the link (my own name, linking to my profile) inside the red freehand circle? It seems a bit redundant to me.

If I am viewing my flag history why would I need to know that I am the one who flagged the post?

[image: redundant profile link in flag history]

Comment: If in doubt I'd opt against removing it - one could, theoretically, confuse "post flags I've cast" and "flags on my posts others have cast"

Comment: @Pekka, Do *flags on my posts others have cast* show in that list. If so, is linking to the person who flagged it really a good idea?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is someone viewing this list might be confused about what exactly it is showing, because its title is ambiguous. It becomes crystal clear by seeing your own user name in that list, however redundant it may be otherwise

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're saying now, that makes sense.

Comment: I spent five minutes examining this trying to figure out what nonsense the link said and what fresh incompetence could have resulted in its appearance on SO. Turns out it's your name. lol

Comment: You used the work link in the title. The question seems to about the fact that it is your name. Are you asking about the fact that your name is there or that it is a hyperlink?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I guess that's the answer........

Comment: @Matt: Both, I guess. The hyperlink is neither here nor there. (Remember, it's just a link to profile and therefore effectively just an extension of the name.) The question is why those four characters, linked or otherwise, are useful information on this page.

Comment: "Do *flags on my posts others have cast* show in that list" No; they show in a separate list. Which, strangely, doesn't display the name of the user who flagged. I could've *sworn* it did before. Maybe they added this very logic recently, except they added it to the wrong view. I don't see why I shouldn't be able to see at a glance who flagged someone else's posts (which can be *very* useful in spotting revenge flags) while I should be able to see that all of the posts in my own flag history were flagged by myself.

Comment: I would assume that the information generated here is that same that would appear on the review history as well. It has more context there but is rendered here in the same way for simplicity sake maybe?

Comment: @Matt: I'm guessing the same, and they simply added a filter for "flags by this user only"

Comment: Came here thinking this was a flag about a link-only answer, got a question about flag history. This is why people put tags - I mean keywords - in titles.

Comment: @BoltClock Sorry about the title. I wasn't sure how to word it.

Comment: Not your fault, I just saw an opportunity to make a point about tags in titles, a separate topic entirely.

Comment: @Matt, both. I just wasn't sure why there needed to be a link there, let alone a link to my profile, seeing how I am the one who flagged it. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I was not bothered bout that till I saw this post. Now I am. :D

Comment: I think this is for consistency with other places that mods can view flags. It looks like the same ui as the flag queue and overlay to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I'll bet you this is because of an internal design that is shared between *all* flagging histories.

You're right that this isn't necessary on your own flagging history. However, mods can see *anyone's* flagging history - and on that it's more necessary, so they know who they're looking at. If you've got one system for flagging history, why change it for a use case that's only slightly different?

Comment: It makes sense, but would be very easy to hide the name if the user is not a moderator.

Comment: *why change it for a use case that's only slightly different?* -> for UX. The current behavior is misleading.

Comment: @Zanon don't bet it would be easy until you've seen the codebase.

Comment: How is it misleading?

Comment: @Zanon If anything it's simply overtly clear. Nothing misleading about it.

Comment: @Nit, if I see my name next to a post, I might think that there are cases where I can see the name of someone else. That's indeed the case, but only for moderators. What is misleading is the doubt that may arise: *Can I see the name of someone else?*

Comment: I disagree, sounds like a searched flaw rather than an actual problem.